# Best Approach for Making Web API calls from MVC app (with option of adding third-party apps)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth

I'm looking for some architectural advice and have spent hours researching without clear direction.

I want to create an ASP.Net MVC 5 app which makes periodic calls to a Web API 2 service (both on the same domain).

Users will sign up via the MVC app (create username/password), then the MVC app will automatically poll the Web API service at regular intervals, without further intervention (polling is indefinite, and user should not have to login again or provide additional input).

In the future, I would like other developers to integrate custom apps with the Web API service, also polling at regular intervals.

It seems like OAuth2.0 is the way to go, but I haven't found a clear example in this particular scenario.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your Web API 2 service meant to be used internally by your other application or are you going to expose it to the web? Also, what do you need this service for?

Comment: Yes, it's meant to be used by the MVC application and exposed for other third-party apps. It will be used for POST'ing data at regular intervals by the MVC app and third-party apps. I want the MVC app to be treated as a separate client, similar to a third-party app.

Comment: Do you really need to authenticate a user for web api service? I think it might be enough to do just application to application authentication

Comment: The MVC app will be used in many different locations, and I need to know which location is calling the API based on unique credentials

Comment: you can just pass the location info to the service, authentication is a process to check if a user is allowed to access your web api service, as far as I understand all users authenticated to your mvc app should be allowed to web api service, so it should be enough to just do the application to application authentication and pass the required info to the web service

Comment: I need to ensure data is coming from a specific location, associated with a specific company/user. What would stop someone from POSTing false data from an incorrect location?

Comment: what do you mean by location? geo location or a url? if you mean geo location how do you think authentication will help you in this case? Please provide an example how you are going to ensure data is coming from a specific location with the help of authentication mechanism

Comment: Let me give you a hypothetical scenario (this isn't how the app will work, but similar concept). If I wanted to track all indoor temperatures at various businesses in a city, I would first have each business register via a web app. Then, I would install an iPad at participating businesses, have them login, and an API would be called every X seconds to report indoor temperatures. 

I wouldn't want just anyone reporting this info, I want to ensure it's the business that signed up. Make sense?